# Xcode crashes when adding a Swift package

Tags: swift, xcode, package

When adding a swift package to a repo adding the package causes a crash.
Have you seen such a failure?  What did you do?

Here is the stack trace:

```
    PlugIn Identifier:       libSwiftPM.dylib
    PlugIn Version:          ??? (17700)
    
    Date/Time:             2021-04-17 14:02:53.780 +0100
    OS Version:            macOS 11.3 (20E5231a)
    Report Version:        12
    Bridge OS Version:     5.3 (18P54555a)
    Anonymous UUID:        E0A63D54-3439-6D85-7A26-1B18A623DBA6
    
    Sleep/Wake UUID:       48028EAA-522A-4F9B-A1DB-08E369AB0C6B
    
    Time Awake Since Boot: 94000 seconds
    Time Since Wake:       44000 seconds
    
    System Integrity Protection: enabled
    
    Crashed Thread:        13  Dispatch queue: -[IDEExecutionEnvironment initWithWorkspaceArena:] (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
    
    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    
    Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
    Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
    Terminating Process:   exc handler [49193]
    
    Application Specific Information:
    ProductBuildVersion: 12D4e
    Workspace/Workspace.swift:1161: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: TSCBasic.GraphError.unexpectedCycle
```

Comment: "OS Version: macOS 11.3" - looks like you are using beta software. Did you try it on a release version?

Comment: You really need to add more information to this question. Such as the OS version you are using? What version of Xcode are you using? What package are you trying to add? If this is being added to an existing project (if it is what other packages have been added)?  Without out more information it is going to be difficult to solve this.

Comment: Thanks folks...good catch on the macOS 11.3.  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had the package before and I deleted it, but it's still in Derived Data. Clearing Derived data in `/Users/<USER>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`, then adding the swift package again fixes it.